# Remove newlines in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, newline

Currently in address column in test table,i have data in following format,

> 12th street
>
> Test avenue
>
> Test_City

but in the output,i would require it in following format,

> 12th street Test avenue Test_City.

Could any one please tell me the query to use to display it in the required manner.

Comment: What are your table and field names?

Comment: Hi matt, actually i dont have 3 seperate columns for street, avenue and city.the entire data is present in address column

Comment: Maybe all you need is `select replace(address, chr(10), ' ') from customer` but your question is a bit unclear...

Answer (score 16):

You can try this:

```
select regexp_replace(your_address,'[[:space:]]',' ') from your_tab;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do??

Comment: @Ankit: replacing the break lines by spaces: `select regexp_replace('12th street
    Test avenue
    Test_City','[[:space:]]', ' ') from dual` gives `12th street     Test avenue     Test_City `

Comment: Don't know why the above was downvoted, perfectly good solution. The only thing I would suggest is to change `[[:space:]]` to `[[:space]]+` or even simply `\s+` so multiple newlines (for example) would be replaced with just a single space.

Comment: This very solution as written solved a major issue for us.

We are creating Ext JS character strings and newline / carriage return issues crept in.

Without this solution I was buried so could not agree more with David Faber -- this is a wonderful solution as-is.  I still have to either include it in relevant SQL queries or (preferred) just use C# Regex in the code behind but ... modifying the data in Oracle directly completely solved the issue.  Thanks, Cyryl 1972.

Answer (score 8):

Just strip chr(13) and chr(10) from the string:

```
declare
   teststring   varchar2 (32767) := ' This is the value

that I chose';
begin
   dbms_output.put_line (teststring);
   dbms_output.put_line (replace (replace (teststring, chr (13), ''), chr (10), ' '));
end;
```

The result:

```
 This is the value

that I chose
 This is the value  that I chose
```

Two spaces since I put in two returns in the text.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
translate(' example ', chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(09), ' ')
```

The above will replace all line breaks (chr(10)), all tabs (chr(09)) and all carriage returns (chr(13)) with a space (' ').

Just replace ' example ' with your field name on wish you want to have the characters removed.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

`select trim(chr(13) FROM trim(chr(10) FROM your_column)) from your_table`